# Are the Weights Reversible in a Mod11 Check Digit Calculation?

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

I  was searching  at work  which check  digit calculation  a
product number used and found  that it was a simple mod$11$.
What I didn't expect was to find two ways of calculating it.
Both are based on the usual separation of digits (here given
by $a_n$) which are  then multiplied by weights (represented
by $w_n$).  The results are summed  and used in a  modulo 11
operation to obtain the check digit $c$:

\begin{array}{cccccccc}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_5 & a_6 & a_7 & a_8 \\ \hline
w_1 & w_2 & w_3 & w_4 & w_5 & w_6 & w_7 & w_8 \\
\end{array}

$$
c = \sum^8_{i = 1}a_i \cdot w_i \bmod 11
$$

The first method  uses weights from 9 to 2  as $w_1, \cdots,
w_8$. The second one (which  surprised me) uses weights from
2 to 9 and an extra step:  $c$ will be subtracted from 11 to
achieve the final check digit.

With some  random tests,  I did confirm  they give  the same
results. For instance:

\begin{array}{r|cccccccc}
a_i           &  5 &  6 &  3 & 1 &  7 & 2 & 0 &  9 \\ \hline
w_i           &  9 &  8 &  7 & 6 &  5 & 4 & 3 &  2 \\ \hline
a_i \cdot w_i & 45 & 48 & 21 & 6 & 35 & 8 & 0 & 18
\end{array}

\begin{array}{r|cccccccc}
a_i           &  5 &  6 &  3 & 1 &  7 &  2 & 0 & 9 \\ \hline
w_i           &  2 &  3 &  4 & 5 &  6 &  7 & 8 & 9 \\ \hline
a_i \cdot w_i & 10 & 18 & 12 & 5 & 42 & 14 & 0 & 81
\end{array}

It's easy to conclude that:

$$
45 + 48 + 21 + 6 + 35 + 8 + 0 + 18 = 181
\quad\longrightarrow\quad
181 \bmod 11 = 5
$$

And:

$$
10 + 18 + 12 + 5 + 42 + 14 + 0 + 81 = 182
\quad\longrightarrow\quad
11 - (182 \bmod 11) = 5
$$

I'm not  sure if  this is  related or tied  to 8  digit only
numbers,  but  are  the  results of  these  summations  with
reversed weights always complementary to 11 in their mod 11?
If so, why? And if not, in which edge cases would it fail?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
   \sum^8_{i = 1}a_i \cdot w_i +\sum^8_{i = 1}a_i \cdot (11-w_i)
   &= 11 \sum^8_{i = 1}a_i
\end{align}